# Building library on Ubuntu, using it in a project on Arch - doesn't build

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I'm building a dynamic library on Ubuntu 14.04.5, that depends on some static libraries (Boost and OpenSSL).

If I use this library in a project on another Ubuntu machine, it works perfectly. However, if I build it and use it in a project on an Arch machine (Antergos), it says the following during the build process:

```
main.cpp.o: In function `init()':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `Util::generateString[abi:cxx11](int)'
```

I'm building my project with the following:

```
g++ -Ldeps -Ideps/include main.cpp -lmylib
```

*deps* contains libmylib.so and the required header files in deps/include.

If I run *ldd* on my mylib.so on Ubuntu, I get the following:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdd24cf000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f10b2f97000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f10b2c91000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f10b2a73000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f10b26ab000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f10b3ff3000)
```

If I run *ldd* on mylib.so on Antergos, I get the following:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcce115000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5a42fef000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5a42cdc000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5a42abe000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5a4271a000)
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055ced49a7000)
```

I'm probably missing something easy, but I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `Util::generateString[abi:cxx11](int)` is a function exported by your libmylib.so library? If so, you may want to recompile that library first and then reattempt the compilation/linking of main.cpp.

I suggest this to ensure that the c++ standard library that each component is linked against is the same version. It looks like libmylib.so was compiled against the c++11 standard library, you'll want to ensure main.cpp matches that. You can always specify which one you're linking against using `--std=` option (e.g. `--std=c++11`, `--std=c++0x`, `--std=c++17`).